# Creating a Map that has a List of Attachments as the Value

Tags: apex, attachment, map

I am beginning to write a trigger that grabs an attachment from an Email Message on a Case. Eventually, the goal is to be able to send emails using this trigger, but right now, I am having difficulty organizing the attachments and Ids into a map to properly bulkify. For each unique EmailMessage ID (the Key in the map), I would like to have the Value be a List of attachments (those attachments being ONLY the ones associated with that the particular email message ID in the key. Below is a snippet of what I have started.

```
trigger hardwareAttachmentEmail on EmailMessage (after insert) {

List<Attachment> allAttachments = New List<Attachment>();
Set<Id> validEmailIds = New Set<Id>();
Map<Id, List<Attachment>> emailMap = New Map<Id, List<Attachment>>();


for (EmailMessage e : Trigger.new) {
    if(e.Parent.RecordTypeId == '01280000000HpXA'){
        validEmailIds.add(e.Id);

    }
}

allAttachments = [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN :validEmailIds];



for (Attachment a : allAttachments){
**Here is where I need to set the Map**
}


}
```

Does it make sense for me to have a nested For loop or to use a different method of accomplishing this? I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code could look like this:

```
Map<Id, List<Attachment>> emailMap = new Map<Id, List<Attachment>>();
for (Id id : validEmailIds) emailMap.put(id, new List<Attachment>());
for (Attachment a : [
        SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Body
        FROM Attachment
        WHERE ParentId IN :validEmailIds
        ) {
    emailMap.get(a.ParentId).add(a);
}
```

The second line makes sure there is an empty list for each Id, then the main loop can get the list and just add the `Attachment` to the list.

Note that by querying the `Body`, you are in danger of exceeding the heap spece limit if the bodies are large (as they can be).